# Installed Wildfly8.0 server in Eclipse, while start the project it is asking username, password?

Tags: java

Installed Wildfly8.0 server in Eclipse, while start the project it is asking username, password?

Comment: Create an account and use those credentials?

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal  **cd** to the   **/bin** 
execute the commands as follows:

go to **WildFly Base directory**:

```
 stpl@darkserver:~$ cd wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/
```

**execute add-user.sh/(add-user.bat in windows)**:

```
stpl@darkserver:~/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin$ ./add-user.sh
```

**Select type of user:**

```
What type of user do you wish to add? 
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): a
```

**Enter the details of the new user to add.**
provide username:

```
Using realm 'ManagementRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : demoAdmin
```

**Provide password:**

```
Password recommendations are listed below. To modify these restrictions edit the add-user.properties configuration file.
 - The password should be different from the username
 - The password should not be one of the following restricted values {root, admin, administrator}
 - The password should contain at least 8 characters, 1 alphabetic character(s), 1 digit(s), 1 non-alphanumeric symbol(s)
Password :
```

**if you do not provide password according to the recommendation it will show the warning like below  . ignore it and enter yes:**

```
WFLYDM0102: Password should have at least 1 non-alphanumeric symbol.
Are you sure you want to use the password entered yes/no? yes
```

**Re-enter the password:**

```
Re-enter Password :
```

**you can enter any value here and press enter:**

```
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]:
```

**Confirm adding user by entering yes:**

```
About to add user 'demoAdmin' for realm 'ManagementRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes

Added user 'demoAdmin' to file '/home/stpl/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'demoAdmin' to file '/home/stpl/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/domain/configuration/mgmt-users.properties'
Added user 'demoAdmin' with groups  to file '/home/stpl/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
Added user 'demoAdmin' with groups  to file '/home/stpl/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/domain/configuration/mgmt-groups.properties'
```

**you can enter yes here:**

```
    Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process? 
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
    yes/no? yes

To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="cXdlcnR5MTIz" />
```

and  you are done adding the user.
for more info check the official [link here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/add-user+utility) .
**You can use these username and password to access management console in eclipse , command line utility, or in web console.**

I am wondering why are you being aked for username/password to start the project. What do you really mean by the phrase "start project" please clarify.